# how to Avoid substring method in java code unnecessarily -- need an xpath query for finding this voilation

Tags: java, xpath, pmd

**Example 1**

Substring creates a new String object. So, instead of
if (nameStr.substring(0,1).equals("-"))
use:-
if (nameStr.charAt(0) == '-')

**Example 2**

```
    String str ="test"
    Str.substring(1, 2); -->this creates additional String Object
```

instead str.charAt(1) shoud be used. --> additional object creation can be avoided.

I have to create a voilation if substring is used to retreive only one character.

**Please let me know the xpath query that creates the above voilation.**

Answer (score 1):

Within `XPath` the easiest way to do is:

```
starts-with(/path/to/element, '-')
```

Returns true if the `/path/to/element` starts with `-`.

You can find string functions here: http://www.quackit.com/xml/tutorial/xpath_string_functions.cfm

Answer (score 0):

Use `XPath` rule below:

> //EqualityExpression/PrimaryExpression[./PrimaryPrefix/Name[contains(@Image,'substring')]]

This itself enough. You can't compare EqualityExpression with String(i.e you compare String with equals)